# AppWidget's background image is overflowing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appwidget

What is the correct way to create an AppWidget with a picture as its background? I thought I was doing it right by setting the top layout's background to a drawable:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/nott_background">
```

But that doesn't scale well for smaller phones. The background is a 9-patch picture available from mdpi to xxhdpi. The mdpi is 162x162, xxhdpi is 482x482 pixels.

The appwidget-provider is this:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp" android:minHeight="40dp" android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/meal_widget"
    android:configure="ConfigureActivity"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/meal_widget"></appwidget-provider>
```

On my Nexus 5 it looks as expected. But, when I test it on a smaller phone (Emulator, Nexus S, 480x800, HDPI) - the image is simply overflowing. First picture is obviously wrong, second one is as intended. (Also notice that in the first pic the corners aren't round as in the second one)

How can I fix this?

[image: Wrong size!]

The following picture is the expected outlook.

[image: Right size!]

Comment: please provide a `image` how it should look like

Comment: It's the second one. Will clarify.